# SQLite date comparison on non-valid Timestring formats

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, sqlite

I want to get entries from a SQLite database by date.

SQLite valid timestring formats are listed [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions) as:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDD.DDDD
```

I have another format in the database that is `D/M/YYYY`

Is there a way to compare dates in this database (and select entries accordingly) without having to select, parse and compare all the `DateTime` objects from all rows in the table?

Comment: `by date` means, e.g., for `3/30/12`?

Comment: @mellamokb example: I want to select all entries with dates greater than 30/03/2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a really FAST query and I am proud of it :p. So here it is:

```
    public static string FromClausePartForDateComparisson(string tableName, string dateFieldName, string idFieldName, DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        string clause = string.Format(@" from 
           (SELECT {0} as filteredId,
                Substr('00'|| -- make day with two digits
                    CASE Substr({1}.{2}, 3, 1)
                        WHEN '/' THEN Substr({1}.{2}, 1, 2)
                        ELSE Substr({1}.{2}, 1, 1)
                    END, -2, 2) AS DAY,
                Substr('00'|| -- make month with two digits
                    CASE Length({1}.{2})
                        WHEN 8 THEN Substr({1}.{2}, 3, 1)
                        WHEN 9 THEN CASE Substr({1}.{2}, 3, 1)
                                        WHEN '/' THEN Substr({1}.{2}, 4, 1)
                                        ELSE Substr({1}.{2}, 3, 2)
                                    END
                        WHEN 10 THEN Substr({1}.{2}, 4, 2)
                    END, -2, 2) AS MONTH,
                Substr({1}.{2}, Length({1}.{2}) - 3, 4) AS YEAR
            FROM   {1}
            WHERE  Strftime('%Y%m%d', YEAR||'-'||MONTH||'-'|| DAY) BETWEEN
                    Strftime('%Y%m%d', '{3}') AND
                    Strftime('%Y%m%d', '{4}')) AS filteredtable
            INNER JOIN {1} ON filteredtable.filteredId = {1}.{0} ", idFieldName, tableName, dateFieldName, from.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), to.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        return clause;
    }
```

And it is being used as:

```
var selectCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * " + 
    FromClausePartForDateComparisson("TABLENAME", "DATE", "ID", from, to) +
    @"WHERE ID_TABLENAME=@Id";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite doesn't support comparing dates (and datetimes) specifically "out of the box".

As far as I know, you have three options (in order of my preference):

1. Use a format that is suited for string-based comparisons (e.g. YYYYMMDD). Here is something to get you started:

   ```
   sqlite> create table foo (d TEXT);
   sqlite> insert into foo values ('02/01/2012');
   sqlite> select substr(d, 7, 4) || substr(d, 1, 2) || substr(d, 4, 2) from foo;
   20120201
   ```
2. Use convoluted SQL to get it done using ["out of the box" functions](http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).
3. [Create a function](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can compare dates in SQLITE by using some conventons
try to save dates in the same Format

SQLITE uses 3 Dateformats (not realy Formats but used ones) 
* String as mentioned (YYYY-MM-DD [HH:MI:SS])
* Integer 
* Real

I mostly use real  for date-fields which are used for comparing
They have to be saved by the julianday() Function

The biggest Problem is, SQLITE has only a small date Converter function, so not well-formed dates can't or will not be correctly converted